# Beta function for a scalar field theory coupled to gravity

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, renormalization, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Is it possible to calculate one-loop beta function for a scalar field theory coupled to gravity. If so, can anybody please provide an argument?

Comment: yes sir,i forgot to add  the one loop, and please excuse me for my lack of knowledge of the subject since i am just yet beginning to learn QFT.And as far as i know,gravity is non-renormalizable and i wanted it for pure gravity and not theories like N=8  supergravity which are renormalizble to 2 loops.

Comment: See page 8 of http://cds.cern.ch/record/280395/files/9504092.pdf